# Open a youtube video in bootstrap modal box

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, video, youtube

I am listing out video data from sql table.

Fields in tha table:
- sidebar_video_id (auto increment)
- sidebar_video_nev
- sidebar_video_link (full url)
- sidebar_video_v_id (video id from at the url end)

What i want, is when i click on each video, it opens and play in a bootstrap modal box. Now the box opens, but its empty and i dont get any console erros.

```
<?php
$get_videos = mysqli_query($kapcs, "SELECT * FROM sidebar_video");
if(mysqli_num_rows($get_videos) > 0 )
{
    while($vid = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_videos))
    {
        echo '<div class="sidebar_youtube_box">';
        echo '<a href="#" id="'.$vid['sidebar_video_v_id'].'" data-url="'.$vid['sidebar_video_link'].'" class="open_youtube_modal" title="'.$vid['sidebar_video_nev'].'"><img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/'.$vid['sidebar_video_v_id'].'/hqdefault.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
?>


<div class="modal fade" id="videoModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close"  data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Bezárás</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Videó megtekintése</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" id="video_modal_body">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

$('.open_youtube_modal').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var v_id = $(this).attr('id');
        var full_url = $(this).attr('data-url');

        var embed_html = '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="' + full_url + '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';

        //alert(embed_html);

        $('#video_modal_body').html(embed_html);
        $('#videoModal').modal('show');

    });
```

Comment: `full_url` return right value? / any error in console or php error log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the `https://www.youtube.com/embed/[videoId]` format as opposed to the `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=[videoId]`. Youtube does not permit cross-origin framing with the latter one.

Comment: Hello! That works! But if i close the modal, how can i stop the video?

Comment: @KissTom87 Well, that's another question, but the simplest way would be to destroy the contents of  `#video_modal_body` on the `hidden.bs.modal` event like so: 
$('#videoModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) { $('#video_modal_body').html('');})